# CSV Product Import

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, products, bundled-product, csv

I am currently working on a new site for a client where most products are synced via an EPOS system.

However, on there current system they control some packages via a CSV and they are adamant they want to continue with this approach.

**Sample of the csv:**

[image: csv sample]

Column A is the SKU for the main product of the bundle. Column B is a piping separated list SKUs for additional bundle items. Column C is the bundle price.

Ideally we would require the SKU for the bundle to be auto generated and images etc to be inherited from the individual bundled products.

We are using Magento CE 1.9.0.1.

I have spent a lot of time trying to find a possible solution for this to no avail and would greatly appreciate any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Importing bundle products is not possible in standard Magento. However, you can use a seperate importer module for that. 
Personally, I am using AvS_FastSimpleImport (https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport), you could use ApiImport (https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport) as well. You can see an example of how to import bundle products at http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/products.html.

You'll have to prepare the data in a way the importer module expects it. I would use a Magento script or a small custom module for that. First, read the data from the CSV file. Second, transform the data to the expected array format. Third, call FastSimpleImport like shown in the example above.

You should have a look at the H&O Importer (https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import) as well. It might be able to do that task without programming, I am not sure about that.